# Search Query Result

Tags: search, query

Since few weeks ago I have an issue with my Search Query Rules. The issue I have is I can't access the Search Query Rules from Site Collection, however I can access from Central Admin. I only created one query rules with 2 Promoted results.
There is not much information in log file.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Did it work before?

Comment: Yes, I did search and i have found if you have more than 9 Promoted Result you will get the same error message and I have created on the UAT environment. But in our production we only have 2.

Comment: there are not any related information in ULS logs ?

Comment: nothing really I will attached them here soon

Comment: QueryLogProcessor: MoveFromUnprocessedToTemp. dd3b7f9f-79dd-e015-dd40-18afe1dc3464

Comment: QueryLogProcessor: MoveFromUnprocessedToTemp in links store: server NP1SPSQL01, database Search_Service_Application_1_LinksStoreDB_06bf776f2a534d1aa8